# Kotlin Collections (map) key value pairs with EditText

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am coming from Swift and I am trying to understand Kotlin.

1. In iOS I had a picker that displayed the keys and stored the values in a @State object
2. How can I use the EditText to do the same thing but avoid the user entered errors?
3. Could this conditional statement be an Enum in Kotlin for the other scoreModel maps/Dictionaries?

   class NewAcftActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

implemented the model like this, not sure id this is Kotlin protocol.

```
private val scoreModel = ScoreModel()

private lateinit var textEditMdl: EditText
```

ignore the rest of these TextEdit views if the first view answers the rest of the problem

```
private lateinit var textEditSpt: EditText
private lateinit var textEditHrp: EditText
private lateinit var textEditSdc: EditText
private lateinit var textEditLtk: EditText
private lateinit var textEditTmr: EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_acft)



    textEditMdl = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_mdl)
```

Other text edits...

```
    textEditSpt = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_spt)
    textEditHrp = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_hrp)
    textEditSdc = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_sdc)
    textEditLtk = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_ltk)
    textEditTmr = findViewById(R.id.newAcft_textEdit_tmr)

    newAcft_btn_save.setOnClickListener {
        calculateMdl(textEditMdl)
    }
}
```

Ran into problems here... Not sure how to evaluate the map collection properly.

```
private fun calculateMdl(rawScore: EditText) {
    var key = rawScore

    if (scoreModel.eventMDL.containsKey(key as Double)) {
            newAcft_textView_mdl.text = key.toString()
    }
}
```

}

model. this only applies to the first TextEdit but is generally the same for each event

```
 class ScoreModel {
    val eventMDL = mapOf(
        340.0 to 100.0,
        330.0 to 97.0,
        320.0 to 94.0,
        310.0 to 92.0,
        300.0 to 90.0,
        290.0 to 88.0,
        280.0 to 86.0,
        270.0 to 84.0,
        260.0 to 82.0,
        250.0 to 80.0,
        240.0 to 78.0,
        230.0 to 76.0,
        220.0 to 74.0,
        210.0 to 72.0,
        200.0 to 70.0,
        190.0 to 68.0,
        180.0 to 65.0,
        170.0 to 64.0,
        160.0 to 63.0,
        150.0 to 62.0,
        140.0 to 60.0,
        130.0 to 50.0,
        120.0 to 40.0,
        110.0 to 30.0,
        100.0 to 20.0,
        90.0 to 10.0,
        80.0 to 0.0,
        0.0 to 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rawScore` is an `EditText` so you can't cast it to Double with `as` since they're not in the same class hierarchy. You have to use the `text` property to get the text the user has typed. Then you can safely convert the text to a `Double` using `toDoubleOrNull()`. It will return `null` if the String is invalid to convert to a `Double`.

```
private fun calculateMdl(rawScore: EditText) {
    val key = rawScore.text.toDoubleOrNull()

    if (scoreModel.eventMDL.containsKey(key)) {
            newAcft_textView_mdl.text = key.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: just had to make rawScore into a variable and it worked just fine